# How do I stop WhatsApp saving pictures to Google Photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, whatsapp.app, google-photos

I have Google Photos Backup & Sync activated. All the pictures I take are uploaded to the cloud. But since I have an iPhone also the photos that my contacts send me using WhatsApp are uploaded. I do not want this. This used to be different on my Android devices. What can I do to stop WhatsApp pictures being uploaded?

Comment: can you could dissociate WhatsApp from the photos library ?WhatsApp Settings -> Chats > Save to camera roll..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have WhatsApp and Google Photos installed. Turning off 'Save to Camera Roll' in WhatsApp settings under the 'Chats' section fixed this issue. (although it won't get rid of the ones that are already present.

To do that, you may need to delete them from Google Photos manually.